# Unable to install Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting the following error when trying to add Firestore pod to **already existing project**:

> [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
>   -`Firebase/FireStore` required by `Podfile`

My podfile is looking like this:

```
platform :ios, '10.3'
target 'ledosMain' do
  use_frameworks!
  target 'ledosMainTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
    pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/FireStore'
  end
  target 'ledosMainUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end
```

I've tried pod repo update, pod install, pod update but I'm still getting this error. What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try `Firebase/Firestore` with a lower-case `s`